# TypeScript: remapping object properties in typesafe

Tags: typescript

## What I want to do

I want to typing a javascript function below.
This function remaps first argument's property names by second argument.

I use the remap function to create query string parameters.
For example, from `{ param1: 1, param2: 2, param3: 3}` to `?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3`.

```
/**
 * @example
 *
 * const original = { a: 1, b: 'WOW', c: new Date(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) };  
 * const mapping = { a: 'hello', b: 'world', c: '!!!' };
 * 
 * > remap(original, mapping);
 * { hello: 1, world: 'WOW', '!!!': new Date(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) }
 */
const remap = (original, mapping) => {
  const remapped = {};
  Object.keys(original).forEach(k => {
    remapped[mapping[k]] = original[k];
  });
  return remapped;
};
```

## My unsound code

I tried a code below, but this is unsound.

```
export const remap = <
  T extends { [key: string]: any },
  U extends { [P in keyof T]: string }
>(original: T, mapping: U) => {
  const remapped: any = {};

  Object.keys(original).forEach(k => {
    remapped[mapping[k]] = original[k];
  });

  // Problems
  // 1. remapped is declared as any, and cast required.
  // 2. All values are declared ad any.
  return remapped as { [P in keyof U]: any };
};

const remapped = remap(
  { a: 1, b: 'text', c: new Date() },
  { a: 'Hello', b: 'World', c: '!!!' }
);

console.info(remapped);
```

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem. What do you want to use the `remap` function for?

Comment: Thank you for your replying Sefe. I added a purpose of remap function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can type this correctly but it takes some conditional type magic:

```
// Converts object to tuples of [prop name,prop type]
// So { a: 'Hello', b: 'World', c: '!!!' }
// will be  [a, 'Hello'] | [b, 'World'] | [c, '!!!']
type TuplesFromObject<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: [P, T[P]]
}[keyof T];
// Gets all property  keys of a specified value type
// So GetKeyByValue<{ a: 'Hello', b: 'World', c: '!!!' }, 'Hello'> = 'a'
type GetKeyByValue<T, V> = TuplesFromObject<T> extends infer TT ?
    TT extends [infer P, V] ? P : never : never;


export const remap = <
    T extends { [key: string]: any },
    V extends string, // needed to force string literal types for mapping values
    U extends { [P in keyof T]: V }
>(original: T, mapping: U) => {
    const remapped: any = {};

    Object.keys(original).forEach(k => {
        remapped[mapping[k]] = original[k];
    });
    return remapped as {
        // Take all the values in the map, 
        // so given { a: 'Hello', b: 'World', c: '!!!' }  U[keyof U] will produce 'Hello' | 'World' | '!!!'
        [P in U[keyof U]]: T[GetKeyByValue<U, P>] // Get the original type of the key in T by using GetKeyByValue to get to the original key
    };
};

const remapped = remap(
    { a: 1, b: 'text', c: new Date() },
    { a: 'Hello', b: 'World', c: '!!!' }
);
// const remapped: {
//     Hello: number;
//     World: string;
//     "!!!": Date;
// }
```

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak 10x :). I added some comments explaining the magic a bit :)

Comment: The most recent additions to TS make it possible to write code that makes my head spin. Using typings like this is pretty cool to make things work, but in production code you'll be in maintenace hell very quickly. I am using conditional typing in my code but I try to keep it simple; otherwise I spend too much time to wrap my head around the typings of my own code.

Comment: @Sefe I just provide the gun, what people do with it is their own doing :P. You are right complex conditional types are hard to understand. It's best to keep them simple, or at least their behavior simple to understand.. That being said I tend to prefer having my code as type safe as possible so I would probably use the typed `remap` above

Comment: In these cases I try to find alternatives that are easier to type. In a `.d.ts` file I would use fancy typing like that to annotate third-party code that has been created with only JS in mind (which is always fair game IMHO).

Comment: BTW, you can drop the `V extends string` and rewrite the following type paramter as `U extends { [P in keyof T]: string`.

Comment: @Sefe no you can't. If you write `U extends { [P in keyof T]: string` TS will infer `U` as `{
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}` we need string literal types for the values. with the `V extends string` trick, ts will infer for `U` `{
    a: "Hello";
    b: "World";
    c: "!!!";
}` which is what we need to do acurate  mapping

Comment: ~ X( You're probably right but for my own sanity I'll not try to brain-debug this typing any longer...

Comment: @Sefe Why not it's fun :) literal types are inferred (among other cases) for generic type parameters that are constrained to a literal base type (such as string or number)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I know it has been two years since you've responded to this, but there is one part of your code that works, and I have no idea why. I have looked it up but only found incomplete answers or answers that were beyond the point.
`type GetKeyByValue<T, V> = TuplesFromObject<T> extends infer TT ? TT extends [infer P, V] ? P : never : never;` with the specific part of `infer`-ing the type itself.
How is `type a = 'abc' | 'def' infer TT ? TT : never;` different from `type a = 'abc' | 'def'`? Because if I omit that part the entire functionality falls apart.

Comment: @GârleanuAlexandru-Ștefan I use that trick to enable distributive conditional types. The `Infer TT` is to get a type parameter I can then distribute over (distribution only happens over naked type parameters)